# How to set to null values sequence numbers?

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
id val
1  40
2  null
3  null 
4  30
5  null
```

I want to get

```
id val
1  40
2  1
3  2 
4  30
5  3
```

I tried to do it like this

```
df_1['val'][df_1['val'].isnull()] 
= df_1['val'][df_1['val'].isnull()].ffill() + df_1[df_1['val'].isnull()].count()
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can set `range` by count number of `NaN` by `sum` of boolean mask, last parse values to integers:

```
m = df_1['val'].isnull()

df_1.loc[m, 'val'] = range(1, m.sum() + 1)
df_1['val'] = df_1['val'].astype(int)
print (df_1)
   id  val
0   1   40
1   2    1
2   3    2
3   4   30
4   5    3
```